# Cascading Style-sheets not being applied

Tags: css, asp.net

I am using Visual Developer 2008 Express Edition

**StyleSheet.css**

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: blue;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.button{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
}
.label{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: green;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

**CssDemo.aspx**

[image]

When I view CssDemo.aspx in Browser (IE 10) I get

[image]

Why isn't the .button and .label overwriting body in CSS?

Comment: The button and label in your code have ids associated with them but you have referenced them with class names in your css. Either add a class to those elements or change your css selectors to `#button1` and `#label1`

Comment: @Shikhar The book I am reading `Programming ASP.NET 3.5 by O'Reilly `never mentioned this. Your solution works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS dot `.` means class in HTML, if you want to style tag directly, leave the dot in CSS.

```
button {...}
label  {...}
```

or use your IDs

```
#Button1 {...}
#Label1  {...}
```